# How do I delimit a named parameter in JPQL?

Tags: jpa

I would like to write a JPQL query like this:

```
SELECT f
  FROM Foo f
 WHERE f.bar LIKE '[:bar]%'
```

This cannot be parsed properly by EclipseLink, which can't figure out that the trailing `]%` is actually not part of the named parameter name.

I am aware of the `ESCAPE` keyword, but I'm not sure that would fix my problem.  What are my spec-sanctioned options?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say: create your query object with your query:

```
SELECT f FROM Foo f WHERE f.bar LIKE :bar
```

And then set the "bar" parameter by calling

```
query.setParameter("bar", "["+bar+"]%");
```

Comment: So your answer would be, effectively, you can't delimit a named parameter in JPQL?  Just making sure I understand.

Comment: All examples using JPQL and wildcards I saw so far, introduced the wildcard as part of the parameter value according to the example I gave. Of course you can use wildcards in JPQL, but only as constant expression and not attached to parameters.